# Unfamiliar partial derivative notation

Tags: partial-derivative

I've never seen this notation before, so I'm not sure where to start learning about it:

[image: Derivative]

I got it from here: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#the_architecture_of_neural_networks (about half way down)

It looks like he's adding two partial derivatives, one for C with respect to v1 and one for C with respect to v2.  That makes sense sort of, but why is he multiplying the derivative against the change in v1 and the change in v2.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a differentiable real valued function of two variables $F(x,y)$, a linear approximation of the change in $F$ when $(x,y)$ moves to $(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$ is given by:

$$\Delta F\approx \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\Delta y$$

where the partial derivatives are calculated at $(x,y)$. Is it more familiar now?

Comment: Ahhh, linear approximation.  Got it.   Just saying that the rate of change * change = actual change.   Thanks!!!